# Putting text input from one view to another

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, transfer

I have tried so many tutorials that I am wondering why I am not getting such a simple problem. I have a view controller called SetBudgetViewController. I have a text field in this view that I have connected as an outlet called *amountToSpend. I have another view used elsewhere in the app that has a label called *amountSet. How do I make the numbers entered into the first text field be displayed in the label in the other view? Thank you all so much (this is driving me mad)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a property in the other view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *amountToSpend;
```

In SetBudgetViewController, in your -(void)prepareForSegue method:

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourIdentifier"])
{
    OtherViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.amountToSpend = self.amountToSpend.text;
}
```

In the other view controller, display the amount in viewDidLoad.

```
self.amountSet.text = self.amountToSpend;
```

EDIT 2: 
Alternative for passing data between VCs not close to each other. You can repeat the action above or use NSUserDefaults.

In SetBudgetViewController after amount is entered:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.amountToSpend.text forKey:@"AmountToSpend"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

In the other view controller, display the amount in viewDidLoad.

```
self.amountSet.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AmountToSpend"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I got the error that the otherviewcontroller is unknown in the SetBudgetVC. I imported the .h file, but no luck. The two views are not next to each other. The EditBudgetVC (which is the other vc) is shown through a modal segue from another view controller made in the storyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you explain what you just mentioned using some diagrams. Also, are you saving the amountToSpend value, in core data or user defaults, for future use?

Comment: I am not saving the amountToSpend in core data or user defaults (I don't even know what that is). What I explained was unclear (my fault). Basically, the OtherViewController we were talking about is called EditBudgetViewController. There is no segue between the SetBudgetViewController and EditBudgetViewController. The EditBudgetViewController is deep in the application's hierarchy. Hope this clarified.

Comment: If that's the case, I suggest you read up on NSUserDefaults. It's the simplest solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok Rick. Thanks a lot for your help. It look like some other answerers explain NSUserDefaults, so I will try and understand it.

Comment: I tried your edit, but it didn't work. I put the first line into `-(void)textFieldDidFinishEditing` and the second line in viewDidLoad, but it didn't work. Any ideas? I can't believe that it's taking me so long to get something so simple. I need some help!

Comment: What is it that didn't work? Can you check whether the data is saved to NSUserDefaults with a NSLog in viewDidLoad of the target VC? Also, add this line [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; after the first line. See answer.

Comment: No luck. I have looked but don't know how to use NSLog. I just want to make sure: should I be putting the the NSUserDefaults (first code) into textFieldDidFinishEditing? I need some help on where the first code should go.

Comment: Hey. I got it to work by setting the text field to delegate:self. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you 
First View where to set User Default

.h File

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtfield;
```

in .m File

```
  @synthesize txtfield;
```

Now on click of button

```
  NSString * text = txtfield.text;
 [NSUserDefault StandardUserDefault] setValue : text forKey : @"textfieldtext"];
```

the push  your view or present modal as you want

then in the next view write as follow

```
label.text = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault]valueForKey :@"textfieldtext"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do I set the name of the text field so that the code can recognize it?

Comment: you have to set the outlet for the textfield to recognize it for eg. .h file IBOutlet UITextField *txtfield; and join the outlet from xib file

Comment: No luck. It says that it cannot recognize StandardUserDefault.

Comment: Should be "standardUserDefaults"... (note the lowercase and 's')

Answer (score 0):

Since you have lots tutorials, I guess you are enough in coding but not familiar with the concepts..

First of all, since these 2 controls are at different viewcontrollers, that means you have to build a connection between them to help the label find out what u entered in the text input.
The connections could be delegate, notification or the plist value, so u will find lots solution here.

And for this scenario u mentioned, I would suggest delegate solution.
Since you have tutorials, try to find the delegate section and realize what the delegate does and why.

Comment: Could you explain what the delegate is specifically? I have researched but am having some trouble understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need a way to know when the user has entered something in your first textview. One way of doing this is to implement a UITextField delegate and overwrite the textFieldDidBeginEditing method.

Next, you need to get the inputted data and send it to the second textView. A easy way of doing it would be to use NSNotificationCenter. Use it like this in your first view controller:

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSArray* objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[textField text], nil];
    NSArray* keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"text", nil];
    NSDictionary* dict =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"firstTextFieldEditted" object:nil userInfo:dict];
}
```

On your other view controller you need to add this on your init method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(modifySecondTextField:) name:@"firstTextFieldEditted" object:nil];
```

And create the following method:

```
- (void)modifySecondTextField:(NSNotification*) notification {

    NSString* text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];

    // TODO - update your textfield here

}
```

If you need to differentiate the sender of the notification, simply do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"firstTextFieldEditted" object:textField userInfo:dict]; -- notice object:textField. You can then differentiate them by their tag for example.
```

This way you have a reference to your initial textfield
I hope this gives you a good ideea of how the NSNotificationCenter works. Good luck.

Comment: It seems a little complicated for just updating a label in another view. To update a label in the same view, you just need to have `self.textField.text = self.labelWithText.text`, so it seems confusing that you would need all of this to update a label in another view. Thanks for the help though. I will look into NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: I understood that the problem was updating textfields one on a view controller and one on another view. Then, if you want to avoid keeping a reference to the view controller in the view, you can do this.