# Can not pass value of textfield to other viewcontroller in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, delegation

I want to pass value of textfield in LoginView to uploadview but UserLogin1 always is NULL ( 0x000000)
This is my codes:
loginvuew.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
```

loginview.m

```
-(IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender{
 uploadview= [[UploadTab alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) andUsertring:username.text];
}
```

uploadview.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *UserLogin1;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUsertring:(NSString *)strUser;
```

uploadview.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUsertring:(NSString *)strUser
{
    if (self) {
        UserLogin1=[[NSString alloc] init];
        UserLogin1 = strUser;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSLog(@"User login: %@",UserLogin1);
        self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@",UserLogin1];

}
```

WHen run in initWithFrame(), string passing correct but in ViewDidLoad is not correct. And UserLogin1 variable always is 0x00000. DO you have sugesstions? Thansk in advance

Comment: have you already tried to set `UserLogin1 = [strUser copy];`?

Comment: @geo: i tried but not work

Comment: btw, `UserLogin1` is a variable and not a class, it should start with a lowercase letter (to fit programming conventions).

Comment: @geo: Thanks but i thinks it not useful

Comment: You might not think it's useful. However, it's a standard in Objective-C. It makes it so other people can read and understand your code. Otherwise it's just difficult to read.

Comment: BTW, you should use either `_userLogin1 = strUser;` or `self.userLogin1 = strUser;`. userLogin1 is not defined anywhere as a variable.

Comment: in .h file : i declare @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userLogin1;(fixed lowercase letter) but it not work

Comment: Use delegate or NSUserDefaults to pass data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396456/putting-text-input-from-one-view-to-another/17396579#17396579

Comment: @NGOT see my change. You are not defining userLogin1 as an iVar. You need to use `_userLong1` or `self.userLogin1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up things I think. What class is an UploadTab ? The view does not have a method viewDidload ! It's UIViewController's one. If it is ViewController then you should allocate it properly with initWithNibName:bundle or smth like that. 
ADDED:
Your code missing actual alloc-init method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUsertring:(NSString *)strUser
{
    // self is nil here! It is in almost every cases done like self = [[super alloc] initBlaBla]
    if (self) {
        UserLogin1=[[NSString alloc] init];
        UserLogin1 = strUser;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: UploadTab is ViewController type.

Comment: I implement - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUsertring:(NSString *)strUser; but it not work

Comment: Sure it won't because UIViewController does not have such method..you should call one of the standard inits in your method

Comment: Thanks, i tried - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andUsertring:(NSString *)strUser
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        userLogin1 = strUser;
    }
    return self;
}
 But it not work, userLogin1 is always NULL in Viewdidload