# How to wait for NSXMLParser to complete in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser, parsexml

I want to wait for NSXMLParser process to complete and then continue with other processes. I use NSXMLParser to parse XML data.

This is my code:

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
   NSLog(@"Did start element");
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
   {
       XML_FIELD = FILENAME_CLOUD2;
       NSLog(@"found rootElement");
       return;
   }
   else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"UPLOADTIME"])
   {
       NSLog(@"found rootElement");
       XML_FIELD = UPLOADTIME2;
       return;
   }

}
```

didEndElement():

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   NSLog(@"Did end element");
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
   {
      NSLog(@"rootelement end");
   }
   XML_FIELD = UNIMPORTANT2;
}
```

foudCharaters():

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
   if (XML_FIELD == FILENAME_CLOUD2)
   {
      NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
      [FileCompletedArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];
   }
   else if (XML_FIELD == UPLOADTIME2)
   {
      NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
      [UploadTimeArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];
   }
}
```

Above code is used to get data from NSXMLParser but my app needs to wait for the parse xml process to complete. Can I use `dispatch ()` ?

Comment: I don't know ParseXML or NSParseXML. Do you mean NSXMLParser?

Comment: @MartinR: yes, i  use NSParseXML

Comment: @NGOT: ??? What is NSParseXML? Is that a 3rd-party framework?

Comment: So you use **NSXMLParser** and not **NSParseXML** ? Are you trying to confuse us?

Comment: Sorry, i confrim i used NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSXMLParser` works completely *synchronous*. When the `parse` method returns the parsing is finished (or has failed with an error). So there is no need to "wait" for it to complete.

Comment: Thanks Martin R.Can you help me more?Can you answer this qustion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647898/can-not-pass-value-of-textfield-to-other-viewcontroller-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment25699999_17647898

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple..

```
NSXMLParser *parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate=self;

if([parser parse]){
   NSLog(@"Parsing Finished");
}else{
   NSLog(@"Parsing Failed");
}
```

Parser will call delegate function

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
     NSLog(@"Parsing started");
}
```

when the function `parse` is called..